# Creating table on kudu through impala jdbc

Tags: jdbc, impala, kudu

I am trying to create table on kudu through impala jdbc by URL

```
jdbc:impala://host:21050/default;AuthMech=0;UID=impala;
```

but error appears Table owner must not be null or empty.
any help?

Comment: please use `database.table` format to create a table. Like `create table mydb.mytable (i int, c string);`

Comment: @KoushikRoy I tried it but still same error

Comment: can you pls share complete command ?

Comment: @KoushikRoy create table my_db.test_table (  
    id int primary key,
    name string  
) 
stored as kudu;

Comment: Can you select any table using that connection?

Comment: @KoushikRoy yes , problem only at creating table at kudu

Comment: Try to give kudu master addresses to create table command with properties tag.

Answer (score 0):

Create table on kudu through impala jdbc need authentication function like LDAP or Kerberos.You need to install one of them and configure it.